# Codio Beginner Questions

Tags: codio

I am new to Codio and would like to ask a few questions about it from more experienced users.

The first thing I would like to know is that does each project have its own "space". By space I mean have its own separate working area, if I install PHP for one it will not be accessible for another? If I install node.js it will only be for that project?

Do I have full control of the server or are there certain limitations?

Can I point my domain to a project that is being held on there or should I set-up a server to deploy to?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, each project is independed and have his own space, all software installed in one box is not available in another. but you can clone a project with a box, this mean everything will be cloned including software and settings.
2. It is not full control for now, you do not have root rights and have to use boxparts for installing software.
3. Codio is not a hosting platform, and custom domains are not supported now, but every project has its own domain name on codio.io. check Project->Box info menu.